# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I want to reference the value of an item `company_id` in a object `company_obj` created from a RESTful API call `cwObj.get_company(company)` and then pass that value to another API call `cwObj.get_sites(company_id)` and then return the object. However, I am getting an UnboundLocalError when I attempt to pass `company_id` to the API call. Through debug, I can see that `company_id` has the desired value so I am not sure why I am unable to then create another object using said value. Does this not mean the variable is indeed assigned? If not, what is the best practice to assign the variable before it reaches the `cwObj.get_sites()` call? Please let me know if any more information is needed, thanks!

views.py

```
def new_opportunity_location(request):
    company = request.GET.get('selected_company')
    company_obj = cwObj.get_company(company)
    company_id = company_obj[0]['id']
    sites = cwObj.get_sites(company_id)
    context = {'sites': sites}
    return render(request, 'website/new_opportunity_location.html', context)

    def get_company(self, request):
        try:
            r = requests.get(
                self.URL + 'company/companies?conditions=name="' + request + '"',
                headers=self.Header)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except:
            print(r.text)
            raise
        return r.json()

    def get_sites(self, request):
        try:
            r = requests.get(
                self.URL + 'company/companies/' + request + '/sites',
                headers=self.Header)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except:
            print(r.text)
            raise
        return r.json()
```

Comment: can u post the code of  `cwObj.get_company()` ?

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: @NalinDobhal Added the object creation functions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/MyFile.py", line 56, in <module>
    sites = objCW.get_sites(company_id)
  File "/MyFile.py", line 29, in get_sites
    print(r.text)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`

Comment: in except block, you are trying to access `print(r.text)` but r is not defined yet. r is defined in the try block.

Comment: @NalinDobhal so how do you suggest I approach `print(r.text)`? What would be a good `except:`? The problem is solved now, but I'm not sure how to handle exceptions for this particular function.

Comment: @garmars: then just remove the try/except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some exception happens in the line `r = requests.get(...)`, so that `r` never gets assigned to and the variable doesn't exist when you do `print(r.text)`.

This is why you should never have a bare `except:` -- you have no idea what kind of exception happened now. Only catch the ones that you expect to happen.

My guess is that 'self.Header' doesn't exist.